# Nobody Likes This Rebus

Tags: word, visual, rebus, steganography

[image: A rebus]

The puzzle's answer is a single word.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could be

> **ABOMINATION** - as seen when we highlight the background...
>  [image: image from puzzle with background filled in; in off-white is a bomb inside the missing O]
>
>  there is **a BOMB in a TION**!
>  (It could also just be "[bombination](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bombination)", which was my original answer - thanks to Joe for pointing out this more reasonable option.)

Comment: You've started looking at the right places... but there's something more going on here...

Comment: @Avi How's this?

Comment: That is quite so!

Comment: how do you see that?

Comment: @avi it's a shame this doesn't work on mobile: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b1zS.jpg

Comment: @Pureferret simply highlighting it doesn't reveal the secret on either desktop or mobile - you have to do some actual image alteration to find it

Comment: I'd guess you want an indefinite article on the front of that, but I'm not certain. It would fit the title a little better

Comment: For anyone curious to see it/try it themselves, copy/paste the picture into PowerPoint->format picture->picture->picture color->temperature and set it to 1600 (not as clear as the above work, but you'll see it/common software to check it out in)